# Different behavior in IE and Chrome for window.location

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have a page with 3 levels. For example, example.com/1/2/3. I have the code below:

```
window.location.replace("");
```

When I run it in IE11, it goes to example.com/1/2. But if I'm in example.com/1/2 and I run that code, it just refreshes the page. It goes one level up whenever there are more that 2 levels. When I run it in Chrome it just refreshes the page regardless of the URL. Is this an issue with IE11?

Edit: Apologies for the confusion. My expectation is whatever the URL is (since the URL is dynamic), even if it is blank, both IE11 and Chrome will have the same behavior.

Comment: You should use `document.location` instead of `window.location`

Comment: Does your page have any frames?

Comment: I don't have frames on the page.

Comment: So replace all occurrences of `""` with something like `"."`..??

Comment: ...or `destination = destination === "" ? document.location.href : destination`. Browsers are quirky things (especially those from the most detested browser manufacturer). Best not to dwell too much on the "why"... just fix it and move on.

Comment: Thanks @spender . I was trying to avoid handling the blank URL but I guess I have no choice.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers are quirky. Especially those from certain manufacturers. You only have to look at the success of libraries such as jQuery to see this. As such, when you notice a difference in behaviour between browsers, it's often non-productive to dig much deeper, especially if there's an obvious fix. Here that would be...

```
var dest = //something
document.location.replace(dest === "" ? document.location.href : dest)
```